# Java array initialization within argument list

Tags: java, arrays

How come the first call to someMethod doesn't compile without being explicit that it's String[]?

It's fine to use an array initializer to create a String[] array but you can't use it to pass an argument.  Are the curly braces used in some other fashion for passing arguments that derails how I'd expect this to behave?

```
public void someMethod(String[] arr){
    //do some magic
}

public void makeSomeMagic(){

    String[] arr = {"cat", "fish", "cow"};

    //Does not compile!
    someMethod({"cat", "fish", "cow"});

    //This compiles!
    someMethod(new String[]{"cat", "fish", "cow"});

    //This compiles!
    someMethod(arr);
}
```

The compiler error is the following:

The method someMethod(String[]) in the type Moo is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

Comment: Its only allowed at declaration time. It's a syntax thing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can only use the `{ "hello", "world" }` initialization notation when declaring an array variable or in an array creation expression such as `new String[] { ... }`.

See [Section 10.6 Array Initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html#11358) in the Java Language Specification:

> *An array initializer may be specified in a declaration, or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), creating an array and providing some initial values*

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use explicit `String[]`, use:

```
public void someMethod(String... arr){
    //do some magic
}
…
someMethod("cm", "applicant", "lead");
```

---

> The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments.

[Read more](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Comment: That will only work if he changes the signature to `String... args`.

Comment: Perfect, this gives me exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use varargs:

```
public void someMethod(String... arr){
    //do some magic
}

public void makeSomeMagic(){
    someMethod("cat", "fish", "cow");
}
```

It's basically a fancy syntax for an array parameter (vararg must be the last parameter in method signature).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curly braces to initialize an array. In every else case it is used to define blocks of statments.