# How to put String arrays into an array of String arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 4 string arrays like this:

```
String[] array1  = new String{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"};
String[] array2  = new String{"here","here2","here3"};
String[] array3  = new String{"hi","hi2"};
String[] array4  = new String{"blah","blah2","blah3"};
```

And I want to put these into an array of arrays that would look something like this:

```
   Array myArray =  [{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"},
                     {"here","here2","here3"},{"hi","hi2"},
                     {"blah","blah2","blah3"}];
```

And then would be able to access element in it somewhat like this:

```
myArray[0][1] would equal "there2"
myArray[1][2] would equal "here3"
```

Hope that makes sense, how could I go about doing this?

I have tried making an ArrayList like this and then adding them but it doesn't seem to work

```
ArrayList<String[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
myArrayList.add(myArray);
```

Comment: That is odd ... you already know how to access your desired array, but you haven't tried to define it that way?

Comment: It seems that you have a typo. `String[] array1  = new String{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"};` will not create array. Either remove `new String[]` leaving only `String[] array1  = {your, elemements};` or add type of array explicitly by adding `[]` like `new String[]{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"};`.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple. Check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information about Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array.

```
String[] array1 = new String[]{"there", "there2", "there3", "there4"};
        String[] array2 = new String[]{"here", "here2", "here3"};
        String[] array3 = new String[]{"hi", "hi2"};
        String[] array4 = new String[]{"blah", "blah2", "blah3"};

        String[][] allArray = {
                array1,
                array2,
                array3,
                array4
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

I corrected your definition so it actually compiles:

```
String[] array1  = {"there",  "there", "there", "there"};
String[] array2  = {"here","here","here"};
String[] array3  = {"hi","hi"};
String[] array4  = {"blah","blah","blah"};
```

The peferred method to add the to a list is the built in one, as changes to the array will be reflected by the list.

```
List<String[]> y = Arrays.asList(array1, array2, array3,array4);
```

one sidenote: always prfere to use the Interface if you define a variable i.e.

```
List<String[]> x
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<String[]> x
```

Comment: good job please from now then post up your future answer like this so it can be helpful for other who may see your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String[][] arraysTogether = new String[][]{
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    array4
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do `String[][] finalArray = new String[][] {array1, array2, array3, array4};`

as below

```
    String[] array1  = new String[]{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"};
    String[] array2  = new String[]{"here","here2","here3"};
    String[] array3  = new String[]{"hi","hi2"};
    String[] array4  = new String[]{"blah","blah2","blah3"};

    String[][] myArray= new String[][] {array1, array2, array3, array4};
    System.out.println(myArray[2][1]);
```

This prints "hi2"

if you do

```
        myArray[0][1] --> It would be "there2"
        myArray[1][2] --> It would be "here3"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Putting arrays of `String` to `String[][]`

First of all, `String[] array1 = new String{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"}` will not compile. You were probably thinking about:

```
String[] array1 = new String[]{"there", "there2", "there3", "there4"};
```

You can do it shorter way (which I will recommend):

```
String[] array1 = {"there", "there2", "there3", "there4"};
```

Now, the answer to your question is:

```
String[][] arrays = new String[][]{array1, array2, array3, array4};
```

Or, again - shorter (and recommended):

```
String[][] arrays = {array1, array2, array3, array4};
```

According to [Java Language Specification 10.3 Array Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3), the longer syntax is an *[array creation expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)* and the shorter one is an *[array initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)*. They're not equivalent. (If they were, the designers would probably get rid of one of them - [Ockham's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).) An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443892/java-array-initialization-within-argument-list) where one can use *array creation expression*, but not *array initializer*.

---

### Putting arrays of `String` to `ArrayList<String[]>`

The closest one to the way you tried:

```
List<String[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
myArrayList.add(array1);
myArrayList.add(array2);
myArrayList.add(array3);
myArrayList.add(array4);
```

The shortest one using [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```
List<String[]> myArrayList = Arrays.asList(array1, array2, array3, array4);
```

And, if you declare `array1`, `array2`, `array3`, `array4` as `final` references, you can use [*double brace initialization*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java):

```
List<String[]> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>() {{
    add(array1);
    add(array2);
    add(array3);
    add(array4);
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows

```
String[][] myArray =  new String[][]{{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"},  
                                     {"here","here2","here3"},{"hi","hi2"}, 
                                     {"blah","blah2","blah3"}};
```

and access just as you said

```
    public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] myArray =  new String[][]{{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"},
                {"here","here2","here3"},{"hi","hi2"},
                {"blah","blah2","blah3"}};
        System.out.println(myArray[0][1]); // there2
        System.out.println(myArray[1][2]); // here3
    }
}
```

Note that there's a difference than to

```
String[][] myArray = new String[][] {
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    array4,
};
```

in that that in the second approach, the changes to an e.g. `array1` will apply to `myArray` as well, so its a mix of static and dynamic initialization, choose what suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Adding arrays into a list:

```
List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(array1, array2, array3, array4);
```

Adding arrays to a 2D Array:

```
String[][] array = new String[][] {
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    array4,
};
```

Also, you are not initializing your arrays properly. The way you have it, you are calling the constructor of the `String` object, not initializing an array so the compiler will give you an error.

Change:

```
String[] array1  = new String{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"};
```

To (add `[]`):

```
String[] array1  = new String[]{"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"};
```

Or declare the array directly like:

```
String[] array1  = {"there",  "there2", "there3", "there4"};
```

Same goes for the other arrays.